# Object method doesn't get run in for loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, netbeans, methods

In this code, I create an array of objects and attempt to loop through them calling a method on each one. The method is part of the objects' prototype.

Here's the setup:

```
function TestObj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

TestObj.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
};

var myArray = [
    new TestObj('first'),
    new TestObj('second')
];
```

I know I can access the method correctly because this gives the proper output:

```
myArray[0].speak(); // displays "first"
```

However, both of the loops I tried won't output anything:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].speak();
}

for (var key in myArray) {
    key.speak();
}
```

Comment: Your first loop works: https://jsfiddle.net/k1h67p1e/ . In your second one, you would need to do `myArray[key].speak();`

Comment: @blex, strange, netBeans isn't showing me anything...

Comment: Ok, it seems to be an issue with the NetBeans IDE. If I open Chrome Dev Tools, it displays on the console there, but it does not display on the Net Beans browser log. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It seems that it was just NetBeans screwing up. I restarted the program and now it is displaying the output correctly. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your second loop `key.speak();` to `myArray[key].speak();`

```
for (var key in myArray) {
   myArray[key].speak();
}
```

```js
function TestObj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

TestObj.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
};

var myArray = [
    new TestObj('first'),
    new TestObj('second')
];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].speak();
}

for (var key in myArray) {
    myArray[key].speak(); /*change here in your code*/
}
```

Comment: @Taylor Liss May i know the version of your IDE.

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion above and I'm still not getting any console output :(

Comment: Ok, it seems to be an issue with the NetBeans IDE. If I open Chrome Dev Tools, it displays on the console there, but it does not display on the Net Beans browser log. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's weird. That works fine, but any console.log() in a for loop won't get displayed.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on Net Beans IDE,But problem would be with IDE console. see this link if it helps you https://netbeans.org/kb/73/ide/javascript-editor.html#jsdoc_support

Comment: It seems that it was just NetBeans screwing up. I restarted the program and now it is displaying the output correctly. Very annoying.